# <meta charset='ISO-8859-9'> is not working properly

Tags: php, character-encoding, meta-tags

This is first time I am doing a project in other then English Language i.e. Turkish. I start code in PHP, but the problem I am facing is to set Meta Content Character set, Following is the important part of my code.
I use this line to define the Turkish characters for my site.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9" />
  </head>
 <body>
  MY CODE HERE ...
 </body>
</html>
```

The line is working properly in Chrome but problem with firefox and IE,

I also replace the line with

```
<meta charset='ISO-8859-9'>
```

The problem is same,

Please give the statement that works with all browsers.

Note: I don't have any error in my console or firebug window, The only thing is firefox and IE is ignoring both of above lines,

Comment: why don't you use UTF-8?

Comment: do you put `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9');` in php code?

Comment: This is working, Thank you. But one more confusion with me in MySQL with the same case. I have two variable to be display on one page, One variable is as I define at the same page, and second variable is from MySQL.

Comment: The variable from the same page is correctly displayed by using this line, but the value came from MYSQL is not properly displayed. Variable 1: "Söyleyecek" and variable 2: "SÃ¶yleyecek". Removing of this header line will display variable 2 correctly but not variable 1. Can you please help me out, or please suggest me if I am not make you able to understand my problem, Thank you.

Comment: My MYSQL schema is Latin5-Default Collation, I am not able to change Collation to Latin5-latin5_turkish_ci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you can try utf8_decode if you want to put your characters from utf8 to iso !
If it doesn't works try utf8_encode or htmlentities("text", ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");

Comment: Thank you for your help, Can I have any other option, Just for learning purpose I need to know that, Is there any other way to put my requirement in simple html page? Thank you

Comment: In html, you have to save your files in the same charset, in Notepad++, you have this option in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

What I actually got is.

```
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $var)
```

is solved my problem. All browsers support this code. Thank you Stackoverflow team and responders.

This is really nice to research with you.